# Facebook SDK 3 login with Activity

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-authentication, facebook-android-sdk

I have read the tutorial at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/login-with-facebook/#step3.
However, the tutorial put the login button in a fragment.
I would like to put the login button widget directly in my existing Activity layout.
For example,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- other layout for my activity -->
    <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/authButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

I have attempted to do so but in vain (crash or incorrect login status on the login button).
Or is it possible to put the fragment in my Activity layout?

Comment: Can you share what the crash is (exception stacktrace)? There should be no issues in putting the LoginButton inside an Activity, as long as you override the onActivityResult method in your Activity to call LoginButton.onActivityResult, or Session.getActiveSession.onActityResult.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me of overriding those methods. I added Session.getActiveSession.onActityResult to onActivityResult(). It works fine. I would like to know more about the other way you mentioned (override the onActivityResult method in your Activity to call LoginButton.onActivityResult). Could you give me more details or code snippets?

Comment: By the way, what is the difference between putting the LoginButton directly in an Activity layout and using the fragment mentioned by the tutorial?

Comment: If you call LoginButton.onActivityResult, it just transitively gets the active session, and calls session.onActivityResult, so there's no difference. For Activity/Fragment, it really just depends on how your application works. I think Google is recommending developers to use Fragments more to accommodate both phones and tablets, but the LoginButton itself doesn't care where it gets placed.